# importing multiple excel files with different schema

Tags: integration, ssis

I need to have a dataflow to import multiple excel files. the columns all have the same name but some column are not present in files but are in others. I am wondering if there is a way to map this and if the column is not present in the file it would just insert nulls or blanks in that column. so just to be clear if we have 2 files for example with column A,B,C. the column A is mapped to the same place for File 1 and 2. Same goes for B and C. We might also have a 3rd file with column A and C. I would like to have A and C mapped then just insert nulls for B

Thanks for the help

Comment: What about the sheet names in the different excels?

Comment: Heres some sample sql to get you started. Essentially you would need two tables One which has all the columns possibles in the excels and another one that you would populate after reading the header information from the excel(here is some info on how to get that - http://cr9itesh.blogspot.com/2013/05/loop-through-column-field-names-using.html) . Once done you would have to build your source query dynamically -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a397ea/7

Comment: thanks, I will try that out. the sheet names can be different but that I have a script to get the sheet names, it is always the first sheet

Comment: Sorry I'm a little late but with some tweeks we got it to work. in case anyone needs to know, to create the new columns we created a sql stored procedure to compare a table with all the columns and a table with the columns in the file. after that the procedure returned all the columns in the fill  as [column] and the missing colums as : " " AS [Missing column]. we then used this statement as sql command in excel connection